# Загрузка файла вместе с другими данными в одном запросе POST используя Jquery и Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть проблема: "**formData.append("id_element",1)**" не добавляет поле в formData. До этого я находил много решений, но они не работали. Буду Вам благодарен за любую помощь!

Код PHP:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

```js
$("#hw-upload_image-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append("id_element",1); // тут не добавляет поле
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            url:$(this).prop('action'),
            data:formData,
            success:function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

});
```

```html
<form action="action.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hw-upload_image-form">
    <input type="file" name="hwImage"> <!-- hw = homework -->
</form>
```

---

Result (from the console)

```
array(1) {
  ["hwImage"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(70) "73b38ef5d1f5849ea800c18990acde94_ce_1920x1200x0x0_cropped_800x427.jpeg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(36) "D:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\php9F48.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(68411)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле добавляется, но на стороне php `id_element` будет в `$_POST`, а не в `$_FILES`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :)